# Nothing is displayed when I add a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, event-dispatch-thread

Nothing is displayed if I change the code from the first example to the second (See screenshots:

Main class:

```
public class Main extends JTabbedPane {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Math");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = dim.getWidth() > 800 ? (int) (dim.getWidth() / 2 - 400) : 0;
        int y = dim.getWidth() > 800 ? (int) (dim.getHeight() / 2 - 300) : 0;
        f.setBounds(x, y, 800, 600);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setContentPane(new Main());
    }

    Main() {
        super();
        addTab("Pythagoras", new Pythagoras());
    }
}
```

Pythagoras (screenshot 1):

```
public class Pythagoras extends JPanel{

    Pythagoras() {
        super();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField j = new JTextField("Hi :)");
        add(j);
    }
}
```

Pythagoras (screenshot 2):

```
public class Pythagoras extends JPanel{

    Pythagoras() {
        super();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }
}
```

Pythagoras (screenshot 3):

```
public class Pythagoras extends JPanel{

        Pythagoras() {
            super();
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add( new JLabel("This works!"));
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot 1][image: Screenshot 2][image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Not my best language, but I think your constructors are private?

Comment: Constructors are always public in Java (you don't need to manually specify it yourself). Anyway, that is not the problem, I have been making constructors for years now, without any private/public additions.

Comment: @Hidde: constructors are not always public in Java. Their visibility rules are the same as the ones of methods. If you have no visibility modifier, the constructor is package-protected, not public.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This is strange, sometimes your code gives the right output as you expecting it to give, sometimes it won't with nothing changed in the code. So seems like your UI Look and Feel has something to do with it.

Comment: @Prophesy: that's what happens when Swing components are not accessed from the EDT. Unpredicatble results. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use Swing components in the event dispatch thread. The whole code of the main method should be wrapped into

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // original code here
    }
});
```

This change makes everything appear as expected in my tests.

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading

Also, be careful that the JTextField constructor taking only a String as argument creates a text field with 0 as the number of columns.

Comment: Please, May you enlighten this thing a bit more.

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits: I've added two useful links to my answer

Comment: Thanks, this was the part that I had forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Math");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int x = dim.getWidth() > 800 ? (int) (dim.getWidth() / 2 - 400) : 0;
int y = dim.getWidth() > 800 ? (int) (dim.getHeight() / 2 - 300) : 0;
f.setContentPane(new Main());
f.setBounds(x, y, 800, 600);
f.setResizable(false);
f.setVisible(true);
```